# Click link after focus is returned from print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, printdialog

I have a web page that brings up the print dialog on load. After clicking print (and focus returning to the page) I need a link to be clicked. Does anyone know a way using jQuery or Javascript that I can do this?

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.print();
        $("body").bind("focus", function(){ $("#logout").click() });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you'll need to use `document.getElementById("logout").click();` to click the link

Comment: Why wouldn't `$("#logout").click()` work?

Comment: Because you said that element is a link. jQuery doesn't trigger the native `click` event on links so they won't navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.print()) 
            location.href = $("#logout").attr('href');
        else
            location.href = $("#logout").attr('href');
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<body>
    <a id="logout" href="http://www.google.it">Link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the `if/else` actually wait for the printing operation to be done?

Comment: it starts to print and change page 'immediately' after the click